# ORMLITE ORDER_BY with multiple columns

Tags: android, sql-order-by, ormlite

I am using **ormlite** in my recent android project. I want to order by on a query on multiple columns in a table (say two columns). How can I achieve that??

Here is the code for a single order by...

```
QueryBuilder<Visit, Integer> qb = getHelper().getVisitDao().queryBuilder();
qb.where().eq("FOREIGN_ID", id);
qb.orderBy("VISIT_DATE", false);
```

Comment: putting another orderBy call after the first doesn't work?

Comment: thanks for the suggession. It works

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> I want to order by on a query on multiple columns in a table(say two columns). How can i achieve that??

All you need to do is to call `orderBy(...)` multiple times.

```
qb.orderBy("VISIT_DATE", false);
qb.orderBy("order-column", false);
...
```

This is covered by the [documentation](http://ormlite.com/docs/order-by).  To quote:

> Add "ORDER BY" clause to the SQL query statement to order the results by the specified column name. Use the ascending boolean to get a ascending or descending order. This can be called multiple times to group by multiple columns.

Also the [javadocs](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/QueryBuilder.html#orderBy(java.lang.String,%20boolean)):

> Add "ORDER BY" clause to the SQL query statement. This can be called multiple times to add additional "ORDER BY" clauses. Ones earlier are applied first.

Comment: oh i have seen the java doc, should have seen the documentation though. Thanks

Comment: I was wondering why it's you who's on all the ORMLite threads.. heh thanks for the library