# Android use OrderBy in ORMLite

Tags: android, ormlite

i'm trying to use chaining `orderBy` for this code:

```
List messages = G.messagesListsDao.queryBuilder().where().eq("group_id", group_id).query();
```

i can not find good document for how to use `orderBy()` chain for this code befor using `.query()` for example this code:

```
GenericRawResults<String[]> raw_result =G.messagesListsDao.queryRaw("SELECT * FROM messageslist WHERE group_id = " + group_id + " ORDER BY received_date");
```

to:

```
List messages = G.messagesListsDao.queryBuilder().where().eq("group_id", group_id).orderby("id",false).query();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call orderBy() more than once, like this:

```
List messages = G.messagesListsDao.queryBuilder().where().eq("group_id", group_id).orderBy("id",false).orderBy("received_date",false).query();
```

This is covered by the documentation. To quote:

> Add "ORDER BY" clause to the SQL query statement to order the results
>   by the specified column name. Use the ascending boolean to get a
>   ascending or descending order. This can be called multiple times to
>   group by multiple columns.

Hope it works !

Comment: i get error for `.orderBy("id",false).orderBy("received_date",false)` dont find statement

Comment: Take a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666847/ormlite-order-by-with-multiple-culumns